# Locale not set Programatically in Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

My application set locale according to selected language in application. Up to Kitkat my code works fine.
After update to Lollipop locale was not set. Here i paste my code to set locale..

```
Locale locale = new Locale("de_DE");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to change the way of the locale initialization. From this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("de_DE");
```

to this:

```
String language = "de";
String country = "DE";
Locale locale = new Locale(language , country);
```

Check out the full response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27490553/2659558

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you can set locale to application by using following code.

---

```java
Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Lollipop Set Default local does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086999/lollipop-set-default-local-does-not-work)   Try using just the language code "de" rather than "de_DE".

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
 public static final String COUNTRY_EN = "GB";
  public static final String LANG_EN = "en";


country=COUNTRY_EN ;
lang=LANG_EN ;
Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang, country);
Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
Resources res = context.getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.setLayoutDirection(myLocale);
conf.locale = myLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```