# Impossible to change locale only Android 5.02

Tags: android, localization, locale, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm using default piece of code in all my projects, in BaseActivity in `onCreate()`:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I tried put here like `new Locale("ru", "RU")` - no difference. The weird part that this problem occurs only in android 5.02 NOT 5.0,5.01. Also there is exist such [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086999/lollipop-set-default-local-does-not-work) so my assumptions there are were significant changes in locale api.

EDIT: I'm restarting whole app after changing locale in settings

Comment: I have the same issue. Here is the fix for this.
[Here is the fix for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android/43938564#43938564)

Answer (score 0):

you must restart the activity, but be aware this won't update the already opened activity(the alreardy in the back stack) , i usually update then call the main activity 
with the following properties in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" #the important
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

funiction to update the lang

```
public static void updateLanguage(Context ctx, String lang, boolean goToHomeScreen) {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lang))
        cfg.locale = new Locale(lang);
    else
        cfg.locale = Locale.getDefault();

    ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(cfg, null);

    if (goToHomeScreen) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm restarting whole app after changing locale in settings

Comment: @grub- weird android bugs

Comment: yeah it works on all versions of Android except this recent update.